# ngModel is not working (Forms Module I have imported)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-ngmodel, angular2-ngmodel

I have imported `forms module`. Also I have included in `imports` section still I am getting error. It is highlighting error in html files only. I am not able to understand the issue.

```
<textarea rows="6" [(ngModel)] ="enteredValue"  ></textarea>
<hr>
<button (click)="onAddPost()">Save Post</button>

<p>{{ newPost }}</p>
```

Component file:-

```
import { Component  } from "@angular/core";
@Component({
    selector : 'app-post-create',
    templateUrl: './post-create.component.html'
})
export class PostCreateCompomnet{

    newPost ='I am Genius';

    onAddPost(){
        this.newPost= this.enteredValue;  // this is the value of ngModel
    }

}
```

appmodule

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'; 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { PostCreateCompomnet } from './posts/post-create/post-create.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    PostCreateCompomnet

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[image]

Can someone please help me to understand the issue. I am new to `Angular`

Comment: Please add your component's code to your question. Also, if you're using a VS Code plugin like the Angular Language Service, it will register errors until your component is part of a module.

Comment: Did you check whether `enteredvalue` has been declared in the corresponding component.ts file or not? Also check for case sensitivity.

Comment: thanks..... I have added the code of component and module files

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the component.ts file as shown below,

```js
export class PostCreateCompomnet {

  newPost = 'I am Genius';
  enteredValue: string; // Missing declaration

  onAddPost() {
    this.newPost = this.enteredValue;
  }

}
```

The declaration for `enteredValue` was missing.

Comment: thank you so much Utkarsh.